# Not getting required result after joining 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a view where i need to get list of all dishes from menu table according to main_menuid for a particular user, But here i need to put some conditions
Currently i am using 3 tables for the entire process (table view for all 3 is given at the end)

```
1) main_menu
2) menu
3) cart
```

1) I need to get list of dishes according to main_menuid

so here if i need a list of dishes below MM1, so list of dishes that i should get from menu table is `(main_menuid is the id of main_menu table)`

```
id  main_menuid  dish    
1        1        D1
2        1        D2
3        1        D3
```

code i used to get the above data is

```
$sql = "select * from menu where main_menuid = '".$mainmenuid."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                print_r($row);
            }                   
    }
```

2) i will also have a userid with me so now i need to display the above list to a particular user `(Let the userid be "1")`, but if he already has added any of the above product to cart earlier then it's quanity should also get fetched from cart and for rest of the items(that are not added by him to the cart but is present in the above list) the quantity will be null, so the resulting view should be like this  `(menuid is the id of menu table)`

```
id  main_menuid  menuid  dish    quantity  userid
1        1         1      D1       3        1
2        1         1      D2       2        1
3        1         1      D3       0        1
```

code that i tried for the above result is (but it didn't gave me the desired result)

```
SELECT  menu.main_menuid, menu.dish, cart.userid, 
    cart.quantity 
FROM menu 
LEFT JOIN cart ON menu.id=cart.menuid  
WHERE main_menuid = '".$main_menuid."' and userid = '".$userid."'
```

Below is a sample view of all the tables that are being used in the above process

main menu

```
id   mainmenu_name
1     MM1
2     MM2
3     MM3
4     MM4
```

menu

```
id  main_menuid  dish    
1        1        D1
2        1        D2
3        1        D3
4        2        D4
5        3        D5
6        4        D6
```

cart

```
id  userid  menuid  dish  main_menuid  quantity
1     1       1      D1      1            3
2     1       2      D2      1            2 
3     2       1      D1      1            3
```

can anyone please tell how to achieve the desired result (DBMS: mysql)

Comment: Are your dbms MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @st001 [tag:mysql] is not related in any way to [sql-server]. Use the tags properly to maximize the chances to get a good answer to your question. There is a quick link to edit the question tags; it appears when the mouse pointer is over the tags. Use it to remove the `sql-server` tag.

Comment: Which tables do the main_menuid and userid columns belong to? (Not qualified in the SELECT...)

Comment: @jarlh main_menuid is the id of main_menu table, userid will come from user table that i will get when user will log in

Comment: Move cart.userid from WHERE clause to ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN behavior. (As it is now, it executes as a regular inner join.)

Comment: @jarlh tried but not working, applying check on user id is not displaying other menu items that have 0 quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move userID to the join as it is eliminating the null values generated from the left join.

```
SELECT  menu.main_menuid, menu.menuid, menu.dish, cart.userid, 
    cart.quantity 
FROM menu 
LEFT JOIN cart ON menu.id=cart.menuid  
   and userid = '".$userid."'
WHERE main_menuid = '".$main_menuid."'
```

However this implies you want some dishes not associated to the user so userID will be NULL in some cases.

Why does this work and not in the where clause?  Because the filter is applied BEFORE the join.  This allows the null values which would occur as a result of the left join to remain.

Comment: You have a little mistake, two "and" in a row.

Comment: @xQbert i changed your query a bit, and its working now new query that worked for me is SELECT  menu.main_menuid, menu.dish, cart.userid, cart.quantity FROM menu LEFT JOIN cart ON menu.id=cart.menuid  
   and userid = '".$userid."' WHERE menu.main_menuid = '".$main_menuid."'

Answer (score 0):

You can't get userid from your cart table directly, if the desired menu item is not in cart. So your WHERE clause filters out these records. Try this request:

```
SELECT  menu.main_menuid, menu.menuid, menu.dish, IF(ISNULL(cart.userid), ".$main_menuid.", cart.userid) AS userid, 
    IF(ISNULL(cart.quantity), 0, cart.quantity) AS quantity
FROM menu 
LEFT JOIN cart ON menu.id=cart.menuid  
WHERE menu.main_menuid = '".$main_menuid."'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on the LEFT JOIN. You should do this way:

```
LEFT JOIN cart ON menu.id=cart.menuid  and cart.dish = menu.dish
```

EDIT

When you do this way, the userid column will be null at the last line, to avoid this, on select you should put something like this:

```
SELECT  menu.main_menuid, menu.dish, 
        COALESCE(cart.quantity, 0), -- will put 0 when null
        COALESCE(cart.userid, '".$userid."') as userid -- will put '".$userid."' when null
```